# Inverse Fourier transform of $ \frac{2+\mathrm{j}Ω}{1+\mathrm{j}Ω}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

What is the inverse Fourier transform of
$$\frac{2+\mathrm{j}Ω}{1+\mathrm{j}Ω}\,?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Partial fraction and writing
 $$1+\frac{1}{1+jΩ}$$

Now taking Inverse Fourier Transformation

$$F^{-1}(1+\frac{1}{1+jΩ})$$ 
$$=F^{-1}(1)+F^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+jΩ})$$

$$=\delta(t) + e^{-t}H(t)$$

$H(t)% $=$  $[Unit Step Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

$\delta(t)$ = [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531134/inverse-fourier-transform-of-frac1ajw) for the help of inverse of 2nd part.