# Solution of an equation depends on Fourier conventions?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Let's say we define the Fourier transform as (sorry for the abuse of notation)

$$\mathcal{F}[f(t); \omega] = f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt f(t) e^{-i\omega t},$$
which then means that the inverse Fourier would be defined as
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[f(\omega); t] = f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega f(\omega) e^{i\omega t}. $$

Next, consider the following ODE
$$M\frac{d}{dt}f(t) + \eta f(t) = g(t), $$
where $M, \eta > 0$ and $f, g$ are Fourier transformable. One can find the particular solution by Fourier transforming both sides (I want to use Fourier transforms for practice) which then yields (again with abuse of notation)
$$f(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\frac{g(\omega)}{Mi\omega + \eta}; t], $$
which can be rewriten as
$$f(t) = g(t)\ast \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\frac{1}{Mi\omega + \eta}; t].$$
Now my question is that it seems to me that if I chose the factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ to be with the inverse Fourier then I would get a different result by a factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ (based on this answer: [Inverse Fourier transform of $ \frac1{a+\mathrm{j}w} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531134/inverse-fourier-transform-of-frac1a-mathrmjw) which I agree with). This seems extremely strange to me since this prefactor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is a convention. What is happening here?

Comment: Why do you say you get a different result? You're taking an inverse Fourier transform of a Fourier transform, so why does it matter where the $\frac{1}{{2\pi}$ factor is applied?

Comment: If I write out the inverse Fourier transform (without the $1/2\pi$ in the last equation and calculate it with complex analysis like in the answer that I linked I get a result that will clearly differ when I include the factor of $1/2\pi$ in the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Perhaps you're playing a bit too loose with your definitions. Your last two formulas are presumably based on a specific definition of the Fourier transform (as is your linked question). The definition of the inverse Fourier transform has to be consistent with the definition of the Fourier transform that was used to obtain your last two formulas. The convolution theorem involves a constant scaling factor that depends on the specific normalization of the Fourier transform (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Convolution_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

Comment: Oh this could be it. I will look into it, thanks!